# How to print system date in this format "2017-04-04T05:30:27.27-0700"

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to print the system date in this format "2017-04-04T05:30:27.27-0700".
Could you please write an sql query for this.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: There's no effort in this question. Which RDBMS? print where? is the data from a table?

Comment: I tried this :alter session 
set nls_date_formate='DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF PM TZH:TZM';

Comment: I will alter your question to be Oracle. Next time please define the database platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF2TZHTZM') from dual;

2018-02-07T11:43:37.47+0800
```